# Save / Write NSMutableArray of objects to disk?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Initially I thought this was going to work, but now I understand it won't because artistCollection is an NSMutableArray of "Artist" objects.

```
@interface Artist : NSObject {
    NSString *firName;
    NSString *surName;
}
```

My question is what is the best way of recording to disk my NSMutableArray of "Artist" objects so that I can load them the next time I run my application?

```
artistCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

newArtist = [[Artist alloc] init];
[newArtist setFirName:objFirName];
[newArtist setSurName:objSurName];
[artistCollection addObject:newArtist];

NSLog(@"(*) - Save All");
[artistCollection writeToFile:@"/Users/Fgx/Desktop/stuff.txt" atomically:YES];
```

## EDIT

*Many thanks, just one final thing I am curious about. If "Artist" contained an extra instance variable of NSMutableArray (softwareOwned) of further objects (Applications) how would I expand the encoding to cover this? Would I add NSCoding to the "Applications" object, then encode that before encoding "Artist" or is there a way to specify this in "Artist"?*

```
@interface Artist : NSObject {
    NSString *firName;
    NSString *surName;
    NSMutableArray *softwareOwned;
}

@interface Application : NSObject {
    NSString *appName;
    NSString *appVersion;
}
```

many thanks

gary

Comment: To answer your edit: just implement NSCoding for your Application class and, in Artist's encodeWithCoder: and initWithCoder:, add lines to handle the encoding/decoding of the mutable array. When asked to encode itself, the array will then ask the Application objects to encode themselves.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`writeToFile:atomically:` in Cocoa's collection classes only works for property lists, i.e. only for collections that contain standard objects like NSString, NSNumber, other collections, etc.

To elaborate on [jdelStrother's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644370/save-write-nsmutablearray-of-objects-to-disk/1644403#1644403), you can archive collections using `NSKeyedArchiver` if all objects the collection contains can archive themselves. To implement this for your custom class, make it conform to the `NSCoding` protocol:

```
@interface Artist : NSObject <NSCoding> {
    NSString *firName;
    NSString *surName;
}

@end


@implementation Artist

static NSString *FirstNameArchiveKey = @"firstName";
static NSString *LastNameArchiveKey = @"lastName";

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        firName = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:FirstNameArchiveKey] retain];
        surName = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:LastNameArchiveKey] retain];
    }
    return self;
}   

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:firName forKey:FirstNameArchiveKey];
    [encoder encodeObject:surName forKey:LastNameArchiveKey];
}

@end
```

With this, you can encode the collection:

```
NSData* artistData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:artistCollection];
[artistData writeToFile: @"/Users/Fgx/Desktop/stuff" atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at NSKeyedArchiver.  Briefly :

```
NSData* artistData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:artistCollection];
[artistData writeToFile: @"/Users/Fgx/Desktop/stuff" atomically:YES];
```

You'll need to implement encodeWithCoder: on your Artist class - see [Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ModelObjects/Articles/moArchiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002133)

Unarchiving (see NSKeyedUnarchiver) is left as an exercise for the reader :)